# Suggestions for a Data Structure for related features

Tags: algorithm, sparse-matrix

We have a set of Documents , each has a set of Features. 
Given feature A, we need to know what is the probability of having feature B in the same document.

I thought of building a probability matrix , s.t:
M(i,j) = Probability of having feature B in a document , given that feature A is there.

However , we have an additional requirement: 
Given feature A is in the document , what are all the features that have a probability > P of being in the same document.

In the mean while all I could think off is a sparse matrix for the Probability matrix , and after it's computed , for each feature run over all the column , sort it by P , and keep it in a linked list somewhere.  (So now , we have for each feature , a list of corresponding features

This space complexity is quite big (worst case: N^2, and N is large!) , and the time complexity for each search is O(N).

Any better idea?

Comment: @yassale: N is large as in 10^3 or as in 10^9 ?  Kilo-large or giga-large ?

Comment: Estimated number of document ? Maximum number of features for each document ? Total number of different features ? It would helps as a general solution can only be a sparse matrix but if you have much more features than documents it can be faster to iterate over each document. What is the complexity to test if a given feature is in a document ?

Comment: @Loic The # of document in the training set is estimated at ~100k , #of features per document - O(100) . The complexity of getting features per document is very big (external service , time lag is measured in seconds)

Comment: You'll anyway need all features for all documents in order to build your structure so it's gonna takes time. Sparse matrix would be of size ~100k*100 = ~10^8. How many different features do you have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of features is comparable with the number of documents, or greater, consider holding an inverted index: for each feature hold (e.g. a sorted list of) the documents in which it is present. You can then work out the probability of B given A by running a merge on the sorted lists for features A and B.

For the "common features expected given A" question, I can think of nothing better than pre-computing the answer for each A and hoping that the resulting list of features isn't too long.